# How to prove that doing something earlier in time increases the probability of success?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have two events A and B. If I do A before B I will succeed. If I do A after B I will fail. Now, the problem is that I don't know when B happens.

Intuitively I can say that if do A as early as possible I will be increasing the probably of success, but I don't know how to express this mathematically.

**Problem motivation**

I travel often with a friend and we often have to get several transports, in chain, to arrive to a place. I always tell him that we should get the first transport possible (A) within the time frame we defined in order to increase our chances of getting the next transport in time (B) - We often don't know the precise schedule of B.
I keep hearing from him we should relax because even if we get the first possible transport (A) that doesn't mean we succeed with transport (B) - after all we don't know when B happens. I actually admire his relaxation (he definitely lives an happier life with this thought) but I really get annoyed because I know (intuitively) that we are lowering our chances of success and I would like to be able to explain him why in a methodical way.
I tried to prove by absurd that if we delay our arrival to infinite time we will never get any transport B, but that was not enough, or I am not very good expressing myself.

How can I explain this? Is my intuition wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is fine, and I don't think a mathematical proof would make your argument much more convincing than it is. However, your friend might be solving a different problem. He might not consider it worthwile to arrive two hours earlier just to increase the probability of success by some minute $\epsilon>0$. Instead of maximizing the probability of success he could be minimizing expected costs. The costs will include waste of time when you arrive too early and the unpleasant consequences of arriving too late. People have different evaluations of these costs, and it might be here that your friend disagrees with you.

Comment: Well we usually agree on the time of departure, the problem is that I tend to be quicker to avoid any time losses that can ultimately lead to loosing connections and he is more relaxed. Regarding the argument... you're probably right, but I like to give arguments with some fundament.